# what way can i fix django DB migration error without deleting migration files

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

what is the best way to fix this kind of DataBase Errors without having to delete my db and migration files and starting to enter data from scratch?

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'store_product_category' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: store_product_category.category_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in store_category.id.
```

while inspection the sqlit DB i observe that there is a mismatch in the IDs of the store_product_category and store_category.id.

is there anyway i can modify the id directly on the DB, i dont want to start deleting database files and migrations

Comment: Trying changing this migration file with exception of these types of ids. Or insert a value for the foreign key.

Comment: You need a multi-step migration to fix integrity issues such as this. Look up "data migrations": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood right:

The model `StoreProductCategory` has a FK - `category`, linking to a model `StoreCategory`.

You have a SPC record with `category == 1` but no record in `StoreCategory` with this ID?

If so, the fix is reasonably simple.

1. Enter the DB shell using `python manage.py dbshell` and run an SQL `INSERT` command to add the appropriate record.
2. Change your model for `StoreProductCategory` and set `on_delete` for that FK. I would suggest maybe `PROTECT` might be appropriate here, but it's up to you - just make sure it's something that will keep things consistent.

If (2) is already done, I do question how this happened in the first place - that would kind of indicate somebody has messed directly with the DB. You may want to investigate who has access and what gets done there.

Comment: thanks actually i dont think anyone has messed with it, just me messing around the project is not in production ."python manage.py dbshell" av not used it before can you point me to where i can learn it in detail

Comment: There's nothing to "learn in detail" with regards to django. It simply drops you into the DB shell for whatever database you are using, so you can run commands directly. 

If you don't know SQL, you could probably just run a regular `manage.py shell` command and do it with the ORM, though it's possible your model restrictions might be an issue - not sure, haven't seen them.

Comment: Also, if this is local, simplest way is just to recreate the database and load new data - that fixes everything :D